# Conjugacy and Möbius maps

Tags: complex-analysis

The following might be obvious but not to me.

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a domain. Take two Möbius maps $\phi\in Aut( \mathbb{D}) $ and $\psi\in Aut(\mathbb{\Omega})$. Assume $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ is a conformal map such that . $f\psi f^{-1}=\phi$.Can we conclude that $f$ itself is a Möbius map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're not interested in the trivial case where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are the identity.  But the answer is still 
no.  For example, $f(z) = z + \epsilon z^3$ (for sufficiently small $\epsilon \ne 0$)
is a conformal map of some domain onto $\mathbb D$, but not Möbius, such that $f(-z) = -f(z)$, and $\phi(z) = \psi(z) = -z$ is  a Möbius transformation of both
$\mathbb D$ and $\Omega$.

Comment: So true. Now what if that domain is $\mathbb{H}^+$ the upper half disk?

Comment: Any conformal map of ${\mathbb H}^+$ onto $\mathbb D$ is Möbius.